# french lemmatization Core NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford CoreNLP for French texts.
I have two questions:

1. I want to know if french lemmatization is available with Core NLP?
2. In some cases the output dependencies do not make sense for example for the sentence `"Le chat mange la souris"`  (the cat is eating the mouse) there is a problem in the token `"mange"` which is typed as adj and not verb, for that it's not considered as the root of sentence.
   But when I use the plurial `"Les chats mangent la souris"` it's correct.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

At this time we do not have a French language lemmatizer.

We will be releasing a new French dependencies model soon with our official 3.7.0 release.  I am curious though, how are you generating dependencies, with the "parse" annotator or "depparse" annotator?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.
I use the following configuration for the parse and depparse methods:

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(
                PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
                        "annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse",
                        "tokenize.language", "fr",
                        "pos.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-   tagger/french/french.tagger",
                        "parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz",
                        "depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz"));